# How to make third list from two lists of strings and one condition?

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements

I have two lists of strings. 
The first list is containing all English words. The second one contains capital letters (A-Z). 
What I need is to create the third list that will not have any containing capital letters.

example:

```
words = ["Apple", "apple", "Juice", "tomato", "orange", "Blackberry"]

let = ["A", "B"]
```

The result of third list should be:

```
new_lst = ["apple", "Juice", "tomato", "orange"]
```

What I tried is just not correct. 
I tried something like this.

```
new_lst = [ ]

for word in words:
    for l in let:
        if l not in word:
            new_lst.append(word)

print(new_lst)
```

I am aware of incorrect code, but apparently my brain did not find any solution for more than one hour, so if someone has mercy on me... Please, help me see it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Milan, and welcome to SO. Please, help me understand it better: 1) you have a list consisting of English words only (not _all_ as in all 500.000+ words of the vocabulary) and 2) you'd like to drop all that begin with a capital letter? If so, I don't quite understand your example: why Juice? That one starts with Capital. And why Orange then? You don't have "O" in the list.

Comment: @DaemonPainter "Juice" starts with a capital that is not in the second list, and "orange" is not with a capital at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your condition will fail for the word `Apple` and letter `A`, but then when `l = 'B'` the word will be added anyway (because `'B' not in "Apple"`).

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) here to make sure **all** letters from `let` are not `in word`:

```py
for word in words:
    if all(l not in word for l in let):
        new_lst.append(word)
```

Or simply:

```py
for word in words:
    if word[0] not in let:
        new_lst.append(word)
```

which can be written as list-comprehension:

```
new_lst = [word for word in words if word[0] not in let]
```

---

Alternatively, you can reverse your logic to **remove** elements instead of **add** them:

```py
new_lst = words[:]  # create a copy of words

for word in words:
    for l in let:
        if l in word:
            new_lst.remove(word)
            break  # no need to check rest of the letters
print(new_lst)
```

Or:

```py
new_lst = words[:]  # create a copy of words

for word in words:
    if word[0] in let:
        new_lst.remove(word)
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Thank you. That "all()" made everything flawless.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `set`'s method to deal with that task, following way:

```
words = ["Apple", "apple", "Juice", "tomato", "orange", "Blackberry"]
let = set(["A", "B"])  # equivalent to: let = set("AB")
new_lst = [i for i in words if let.isdisjoint(i)]
print(new_lst)  # ['apple', 'Juice', 'tomato', 'orange']
```

Note that I used `let` which is `set`, thus has method `isdisjoint`, which accepts *iterable*, so there is no need for implicit conversion of argument to `set`.